# Kolmogorov-Smirnov-Test - which values are compared with each other?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

The Kolmogorov-Smirnov-Test can be used to test if a given sample-distribution equals a reference distribution.

I'm sorry to give you the link to the German wikipedia, but the english article differs and my question simply refers to a formula: [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorow-Smirnow-Test)

It states that we need to compute the maximum of these terms:

```
d_{o,i} = abs(S(x_i)-F_0(x_i))
d_{u,i} = abs(S(x_{i-1}-F_0(x_i))
```

And then compare `max(d_o, d_u)` with a critical value.

I do understand that the KS-test compares the CDF of the sample distribution with the CDF of the hypothesized distribution. I can also understand why we compute `d_o`, as it is the difference between these two CDFs. However, I don't understand what the second term (`d_u`) is being used for.

Can someone kindly explain this to me?